# how to get Request URL upon page load in the browser

Tags: java, selenium

Is there a way to get the Request URL in chrome browser upon page load when I navigate to a certain URL. I am trying to do it using selenium and java but it seems not really working to what I want to happen so I did not include the codes here. I only put the developer tool (F12) in chrome where I need to get the Request URL.

[image]